# Entity Framework 6.4.4 (.NET 4.7.2) - No connection string named

Tags: entity-framework

Good day,

I've created a C# .NET 4.7.2 class library project which integrates EF6.  When the parent project makes any call to the DLL for db access, the above exception is thrown.

A common solution is to include a reference to EF in the parent project and to copy the connection string element from the class library's app config file.  This indeed works, but is not ideal.  I really envision all of these settings encapsulated within the DLL.

Anyone have a work-around?

Thanks.

Comment: There are sooo many questions on this topic. Please try to find them.

Comment: From where do you think I derived the common solution from above?

Comment: I don't know, but most likely these solutions also mentioned that they're not only common but also inevitable.